Cannot find ginsim and other packages
So I have a project coming up and I have to use a jupyter notebook with necessary packages in order to do so.
I have installed the necessary packages and an application(Ginsim), but python doesn't seem to detect them.
I have pasted the code block and the error below it
import ginsim
import biolqm
import maboss
import pypint
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd # for the visualization of lists of states
from colomoto_jupyter import tabulate # for fixpoint table display
from itertools import combinations  # for iterating over sets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for modifying plots

The error for this block is pasted below:

{
    "name": "FileNotFoundError",
    "message": "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import ginsim
      2 import biolqm
      3 import maboss

File c:\\Users\\HP\\miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\ginsim\\__init__.py:6
      3 import re
      4 import sys
----> 6 import biolqm
      8 from colomoto_jupyter import *
      9 from colomoto_jupyter.sessionfiles import new_output_file

File c:\\Users\\HP\\miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\biolqm\\__init__.py:13
     10 import pandas as pd
     11 import numpy as np
---> 13 from ginsim.gateway import japi, restart
     14 from ginsim.state import *
     16 from py4j.java_gateway import JavaObject

File c:\\Users\\HP\\miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\ginsim\\gateway.py:61
     58     if __env:
     59         module._japi_start()
---> 61 start()
     62 atexit.register(stop)

File c:\\Users\\HP\\miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\ginsim\\gateway.py:26, in start()
     24 def start():
     25     assert (not __env)
---> 26     __env[\"proc\"] = subprocess.Popen([\"GINsim\", \"-py\"], \\
     27                         stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
     28     port = int(__env[\"proc\"].stdout.readline().strip())
     30     # start the gateway and return the entry point (GINsim's ScriptLauncher)

File c:\\Users\\HP\\miniconda3\\Lib\\subprocess.py:1026, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize, process_group)
   1022         if self.text_mode:
   1023             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
   1024                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
-> 1026     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
   1027                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
   1028                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
   1029                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1030                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1031                         errread, errwrite,
   1032                         restore_signals,
   1033                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
   1034                         start_new_session, process_group)
   1035 except:
   1036     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
   1037     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File c:\\Users\\HP\\miniconda3\\Lib\\subprocess.py:1538, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session, unused_process_group)
   1536 # Start the process
   1537 try:
-> 1538     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1539                              # no special security
   1540                              None, None,
   1541                              int(not close_fds),
   1542                              creationflags,
   1543                              env,
   1544                              cwd,
   1545                              startupinfo)
   1546 finally:
   1547     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
   1548     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
   (...)
   1551     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1552     # ReadFile will hang.
   1553     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1554                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1555                          errread, errwrite)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
}

I would love to know what's going on and a solution to this problem. Thanks
I have tried installing all necessary packages using Conda and also the regular pip3 way and they seem to work fine.
I have pasted the conda list below for bio_env which is the environment and interpreter I'm using for VS code.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\HP\miniconda3\envs\bio_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
boolean.py                4.0                        py_0    colomoto
ca-certificates           2024.9.24            haa95532_0
cffi                      1.17.0           py38h4cb3324_0    conda-forge
clingo                    5.7.1            py38h5e21985_1    conda-forge
colomoto_jupyter          0.8.9                      py_0    colomoto
espresso-logic-minimizer  9999                          0    colomoto
ginsim                    3.0.0b                       12    colomoto
ginsim-python             0.4.5                      py_0    colomoto
intel-openmp              2024.2.1          h57928b3_1083    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              25_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              25_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_1
libhwloc                  2.11.1          default_h8125262_1000    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              25_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.13.5               h442d1da_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.3.1                h2466b09_2    conda-forge
mkl                       2024.2.2            h66d3029_14    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.24.4           py38h1d91fd2_0    conda-forge
nusmv                     2.6.0                         0    colomoto
openjdk                   22.0.1               h57928b3_1    conda-forge
openssl                   3.4.0                h2466b09_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.0.3            py38hf08cf0d_1    conda-forge
pip                       24.2             py38haa95532_0
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                h2466b09_4    conda-forge
py4j                      0.10.9.7           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.22               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydot                     1.2.4                      py_0    colomoto
pyparsing                 3.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.8.20               h8205438_0
python-dateutil           2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2024.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pytz                      2024.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                75.1.0           py38haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.5                pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.45.3               h2bbff1b_0
symlink-exe-runtime       1.0                  hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.13.0            hc790b64_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_1    conda-forge
vc                        14.40                h2eaa2aa_1
vc14_runtime              14.42.34433         he29a5d6_23    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.42.34433         hdffcdeb_23    conda-forge
wheel                     0.44.0           py38haa95532_0

In VS code I did use the miniconda interpreter but it still wasn't working.

Please read the top two high scoring answers here under the post entitled 'Conda environments not showing up in Jupyter Notebook'. You need to connect the kernel to the packages. Just 'installing' isn't enough. Options are covered there. Alternatively, you may be able to just run the magic install command %conda install conda-forge::gensim, and then restart the kernel before your run import gensim, based on here and ....

 here.
